# Have I simplified this partial differential as much as possible?

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics

Let $$\psi = 2\left(\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} - \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Not very good with the software as you can see so help with that would be great...

Am I correct when I say "partial $\psi$ by partial $y$" is the following?:

$$\frac{2x(x^2+y^2) - 8xy^2 - 2x(x^2+y^2)^2 + 4xy^2(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$$

$\psi$ is the streamfunction of a volvox cell, and our project is to model the swim of this cell. We are told $u$=partial $\psi$ by partial $y$, and $v=-$(partial $\psi$ by partial $x$).

Comment: When you say "partial $\psi$ by \partial y" do you mean $$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Like I said, I'm no wiz with the writing software, so thanks

Comment: For future reference, just put a '\' in front of the word "partial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this is easier, but:

$$ u=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} = \frac{2 x \left(-x^4+x^2+y^4-3 y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3}$$

$$ v=-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=-\frac{2 y \left(x^4-3 x^2-y^4+y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3} $$

Comment: does that numerator equal mine? I'm guessing you just expanded the brackets and simplified, right?

Comment: Basically yes! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot... For some reason it won't let me edit, but I'm guessing you meant x in the denominator of the second partial..?

Comment: @Douglas: Yes it should be x. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm given particle paths dependent on time and u and v, and find u and v!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you think this is an answer, please accept as an answer.